# Vista Update failed

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

Hello i have a problem with some vista updates using the windows update feature. It seems the updates always fail and i get a slew of error codes. googling them I have done all the recommended suggestions... and yet it still fails. It looks like almost windows update doesnt want to just download the files
the error codes are 80072efp and 800401fp
some of the updates include silverlight to the .net framework to nvidia drivers

I have followed basic windows update help and Google search results.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like system restore/reinstall is the fix for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try just installing "1" update works 4 me =) (remember just 1 update if it don't work pick another update)

Answer (score 1):

I searched for those error codes and can't find anything associated with Windows Update errors.

Have you looked at the Windows Update log? Are there any errors in there? See [How to read Windowsupdate.log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093) from Microsoft Support if you don't know how to find the file.

If you're unsure of how to read the log once you find it, you can always use a website like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), copy all of the text there and update your question with the link pastebin provides you.

Comment: 1 Update at a time makes zero difference manual updates of the .net framework 3.5 fail as well interestingly enough pastebin.com/m6aba8d9a is the pastebin of todays work. I have messed with IE settigns with proxies lans and firewalls... Not sure what to do